No pop up to ask a user’s location within the app in MacOS
I have a map tool app in MacOS which needs request Location permission to show MapUserLocationButton.
During development, the request for permission can pop up for the first run in my mac, but when it comes to the Apple review, they never see that.
My mac is Macbook air M2 2022, 14.5 (23F79).
Of course, enable App Sandbox - Location and fill up the Privacy - Location When in Use Usage Description
Code:
//
//  LocationManager.swift
//

import MapKit

@Observable
class LocationManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = LocationManager()
    
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    var isReady: Bool = false
    var showingAlert = false
//    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    
    var isAuthorized: Bool {
#if os(macOS)
        .authorized == manager.authorizationStatus
#else
        .authorizedWhenInUse == manager.authorizationStatus
#endif
    }
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        setup()
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        isReady = isAuthorized
#if os(macOS)
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            checkStatus()
        } else {
            showingAlert = true
        }
#else
        checkStatus()
#endif
    }
    
    private func checkStatus() {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .notDetermined:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
#if os(macOS)
#else
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
#endif
#if os(macOS)
        case .restricted, .denied:
            showingAlert = true
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
#else
//        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
//            manager.requestLocation()
#endif
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        isReady = isAuthorized
        guard isReady else { return }
//        manager.requestLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
//        location = locations.last?.coordinate
    }
}

